# moving in a text box with the arrow key

Tags: vb.net, textbox

I am trying to replicate the Microsoft notepad application when characters are selected in a textbox, the cursor is at the beginning of the selection and I begin pressing the Right arrow Key.

Each Right Arrow KeyDown decreases the selection length until selection length equals zero.

My Question, From this point, how do I now make the Characters get selected and continue to move the cursor to the right?

Comment: Have a Sub trigger from Right Arrow KeyPress (Not KeyDown) that deselects the first character that is selected. You pretty much answered your own question..

Comment: Doesn't that only work when the shift key is pressed, too?  What works in NotePad should work in a TextBox.  Should mark your question as Web, WinForms, WPF, etc.

Comment: Yes, The Shift Key has to be pressed.  Keypress event is defined as:

Comment: The onkeypress event handler handles an event that occurs when an alphanumeric key is pressed.  The Arrow key is not an Alphanumeric key.  Where can I find documentation and examples of working with Keypress, keydown, keyup?

Comment: What I was hinting at, is that it should just work "as is" without you adding any code.  It's unclear to me what the issue is.

Comment: As LarsTech suggests, the Windows Forms `TextBox` control already works that way by default.  If you hold down the Shift key and press an arrow key then it will select text exactly as it happens in Notepad.  Unless there's something that you haven't told us, you're trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist.

Comment: IN my Text Editor, I encounter Tokens, both a start and an end token.  When these tokens are encountered, I need to do additional moves either forward or backward to select the whole token instead of just a character.  I am trying to move the selection start and selection length to properly select the entire tokenated string as a single character.  With out the Shift key, I just jump to the beginning or end of tokens and set the selection length to 0.

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, this should already work. no replication needed just hold down shift as you press the right arrow key.

to provide some logic with the selected text you can use the event SelectionChanged
and the selected text is exampleTextBox.SelectedText;

also note.. this will also be fired when the mouse selects the text as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Private Sub TextBox1_KeyUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyUp
        If e.KeyValue = 37 Then
            TextBox1.Location = New Point(TextBox1.Location.X - 20, TextBox1.Location.Y)
        End If
        If e.KeyValue = 38 Then
            TextBox1.Location = New Point(TextBox1.Location.X, TextBox1.Location.Y - 20)
        End If
        If e.KeyValue = 39 Then
            TextBox1.Location = New Point(TextBox1.Location.X + 20, TextBox1.Location.Y)
        End If
        If e.KeyValue = 40 Then
            TextBox1.Location = New Point(TextBox1.Location.X - 20, TextBox1.Location.Y + 20)
        End If
    End Sub
```